# Missing OpenGL symbol _CGLGetCurrentContext, referenced from CoreVideo

Tags: macos, libraries

A program I'm trying to run fails with the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _CGLGetCurrentContext
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
```

If you must know, I was trying to create a `glutin` window in Rust, and got the error when i did `cargo run`.

Why would there be a dynamic-link error like this between two core libraries that come with OSX? Has anyone else come across this error or one like it? I'm using El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directories where the libraries I was using were located fixed it for me. In my case, it was:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql94:/usr/lib
```